# The rep counter and cap mechanism are not adding up

Tags: bug, status-norepro, daily-reputation-limit

Okay, usually I don't like "what's going on with my rep cap" questions, so sorry for this; things just don't seem to be lining up for me today, though. There were [service problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67114/stack-overflow-outage) earlier, which makes me wonder if something out-of-the-ordinary is going on, even though MSO was reportedly not affected. My `/reputation` results:

```
 2     67012 (10)
 2     67071 (10)
 2     67040 (10)
 2     67071 (10)
 2     67071 (10)
 2     67012 (10)
 2     67071 (10)
 2     67039 (10)
 2     67071 (10)
 2     67071 (10)
 2     67039 (10)
 2     67071 (10)
 2     67071 (10)
 1     66934 (15)
 2     67039 (10)
 3     67143 (-1)
 2     67144 (10)
 1     67144 (15)
 2     67144 (10)
-- 2010-10-09 rep +189
```

Sixteen upvotes, two accepted answers and a downvote do equal 189 rep, which all told is still short of the cap value, 200. Without the accepts, that's 159. There are no square brackets in my rep report, and my `rep cap was reached via rep from upvotes *only* on x days` counter didn't go up. So, no sign of hitting the rep cap.

[image: screenshot of rep tab]

The envelope page *does* shows signs of capping. In short, the two rep lists don't sync. I did click on "reputation" and "today" manually. Individually, the tallies on the two pages do add up correctly. As far as I know, nothing of mine — at least, nothing that received votes — has been deleted recently. What's going on here?

EDIT:
This appeared a few minutes ago. The "hit cap" counter went up a tick, too. Maybe caching is to blame? It's looking more like Ether's answer is correct.

```
 2     67144 (10)
 2     67148 (10)
 2     67144 (10)
 2     67148 (10)
 2     67148 [1]
 2     67148 [0]
-- 2010-10-09 rep +230
```

Comment: Isn't the cap 150? (Or maybe it is 160, less the -1)

Comment: @Hogan, the rep cap has, and always has had, a base value of 200.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rep cap kicking in a little too early?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46673/rep-cap-kicking-in-a-little-too-early)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a sign of serial upvoting that was nullified after you received enough upvotes to push you over the cap.  I encountered this several months ago; the false reputationless votes are still visible to this day on my recent activity page.

I documented the issue [at this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46673/rep-cap-kicking-in-a-little-too-early/46685#46685).

Comment: Hmmm. This doesn't seem quite right to me. Even in the list where all of the votes count, I didn't reach 200 rep. Also, I didn't think the serial voting script ran in the middle of the day, though I could be misremembering that. If this _is_ correct, that means serial upvoting removes you from consideration for `rep cap was reached via rep from upvotes *only* on x days`, which seems like it can't be right.

Comment: @Pop: (under my theory) there would have been additional votes, that cumulatively with your visible votes pushed you over the cap, that are no longer in the system.  (Added link to how it looks for me -- which seems to match your symptoms.)

Comment: wow, that's a lot of serial upvotes. You're rather popular!